# Typescript cannot extends Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface

Tags: typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm following a tutorial from Autodesk to create a new viewer tool, but using Typescript. However, when I tried extending ToolInterface, I got :

TS2689  (TS) Cannot extend an interface 'Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface'. Did you mean 'implements'?

The error disappears if I use implements, but then I cannot use super() in the constructor, as in the tutorial stated. Can I get some help on this?
In the index.d.ts of forge-viewer, the ToolInterface is defined as Interface, not Class

This is the tutorial I'm following:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-tools-forge-viewer

Comment: The thing called tool interface in their example is not an interface so I'm confused as to why typescript would tell you it is. You'll have to show the code you're using.

Comment: I didn't get far since that's the first line of the code. This is all I have:


const ToolName = 'TransformScaleTool';

const ToolOverlayName = 'TransformScaleOverlay';

export default class TransformScaleTool implements Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface {
  state = '';

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = '';
  }

}

Comment: The project is very big so I can't send everything up here. But when I use implements for ToolInterface, Visual studio points to index.d.ts in node_modules/forge-viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone correctly explained in the comments, `Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface` is actually a class. The [TypeScript definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/forge-viewer/index.d.ts#L866-L888) incorrectly defines it as an interface which is then causing issues.

We will need to update the TypeScript defs but in the meantime, you could try and define your own tool as a simple class, not extending or implementing anything, and when registering the tool with the viewer using `viewer.toolController.registerTool`, you could force-type it to whichever type you need, for example:

```js
viewer.toolController.registerTool(myTool as Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface);
```